# Store for old mac adapters

Tags: vga-adapter, video-adapter

I'm traveling and hoping to quickly obtain a very old adapter in order to plug my 2006 MacBook Pro into a modern display. The laptop has a DVI port, which I believe is the only display output for it.

So I'm trying to obtain something like this [DVI to VGA adapter](https://www.macpartsdepot.com/index.php/922-4726-dvi-to-vga-adapter-titanium-aluminum-powerbook.html) or a DVI to HDMI adapter. The tricky thing is I need to obtain this in 32 hours for a job interview, so it looks as though mail order is not an option. Transferring files to another computer might be an option, but it would be a little more awkward.

Is there a brick and mortar store that carries mac adapters that are this old? In case it is relevant, I am in the Boston, MA area. Not sure if the official Apple Store would carry them anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best Buy has many adapters, including [this DVI to HDMI converter](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/rocketfish-hdmi-to-dvi-adapter-white/9205898.p?id=1218058779773&skuId=9205898).